# String.replace(regex, string) to replace content from XML

Tags: java, xml, string

I have an XML in the form of a string.

```
<Message>   
 <Header>
    <MsgId></MsgId>
    <ClientAppSeq>CNB110833</ClientAppSeq>
    <ClientAppGrpSeq>CNB</ClientAppGrpSeq>
    <Status>
        <System>1111111111</System>
        <StatusCode>2222222222</StatusCode>
        <Severity>3333333333</Severity>
        <StatusDesc>4444444444</StatusDesc>
    </Status>
</Header>
<TrxSvcRq>
    <Tx123Rq>
        <ContentHeader>
            <Filler1></Filler1>
            <MessageType></MessageType>
            <MessageLength></MessageLength>
            <CycleNumber>170523</CycleNumber>
            <MessageNumber>200257</MessageNumber>
        </ContentHeader>
        <TitleHeader>
             <MessageNumber>abcdefg</Message>
             <Title>HIHIHIHI</Title>
        </TitleHeader>
    </Tx123Rq>
 </TrxSvcRq>
</Message>
```

I want to replace the 20057 only under the

```
<ContentHeader></ContentHeader>
```

How do I do it?

Can Somebody help me ?

thank you

Comment: `str.replace("<MessageNumber>200257</MessageNumber>", "<MessageNumber>123456</MessageNumber>")`.

Comment: Note: the first parameter of `String.replace` isn't a regex (as in the title): it's a literal string. If you want regexes (which you don't actually need here), use `String.replaceAll`.

Comment: thank you for the reply..  but actually we don't know what's the xml string coming... <MessageNumber>200257</MessageNumber> could be..<MessageNumber>568746</MessageNumber>.... how do I do it?

Comment: @bill please see my answer

Comment: **All of the answers provided here are dangerously brittle.**  ***Use an real XML parser instead***.  Many examples can be found for doing this the right way with a real XML parser, including code shown in the duplicate link.

Comment: @kjhughes thank you for your advice.. this is the second option that my team leader provide to me...     the first option --- XML parser..  he is not interested in it.. ...

Comment: coz he does not want to run parser each time when controller got called...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
str = str.replace("<MessageNumber>200257</MessageNumber>", "<MessageNumber>123456</MessageNumber>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to perfom a simple replacement on the string :

```
String xml = "<Message>...</Message>"
xml = xml.replace("Number>200257</Message", "Number>123456</Message")
```

You don't need to have the whole balise into

Answer (score 0):

```
xml = xml.replaceFirst("(?<=\<MessageNumber>)\d*", newValue);
```

Will replace whatever value is present in the  element with whatever newValue you want to give it (assuming newValue and xml are both String objects).

Comment: thank you, I will try then get back to you...   but what if  ...I only want to replace the value of <MessageNumber></MessageNumber>  only under the <ContentHeader></ContentHeader> ?

Comment: you mean, you might have other MessageNumber elements in the xml String?

Comment: yes, btw, above code works fine

Comment: please see the post I updated... thank you

Comment: If the one you want to change is always above the other/s, you could simply use xml.replaceFirst( ... ) instead of xml.replaceAll( ... ). I've edited my answer to include this change.

Comment: replaceFirst  only replace the first <MessageNumber></MessageNumber>...  but what I want is only under <ContentHeader></ContentHeader>.......